# simulate click event and test function that call history push (jest-enzyme)

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I try to test component with a button that triggers function, the function takes a state from useState and navigate to a new route with a parameter inside. How can I test the function?
I got an error :

```
TypeError: history.push is not a function
```

Component:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./Join.css";
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

const Join = () => {
  const history = new useHistory();
  const [joinFormField, setJoinFormField] = useState({
    username: "",
    room: "JavaScript",
  });

  const changeFormHandler = (e) => {
    setJoinFormField({
      ...joinFormField,
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
    });
  };

  const joinChatHandler = () => {
    history.push("/chat", {
    user: joinFormField,
  });
  };

  return (
    <div className="JoinContainer">
      <header className="JoinHeader">
        <h1>
          <i className="fas fa-comments"></i> DeveloperChat
        </h1>
      </header>
      <main className="JoinMain">
        <form className="Form">
          <div className="FormControl">
            <label className="Label">NickName</label>
            <input
              className="Input"
              type="text"
              name="username"
              id="username"
              placeholder="Enter nickname..."
              required
              value={joinFormField.userName}
              onChange={changeFormHandler}
            />
          </div>
          <div className="FormControl">
            <label className="Label">Choose Room</label>
            <select
              className="RoomSelect"
              name="room"
              id="room"
              value={joinFormField.room}
              onChange={changeFormHandler}
            >
              <option value="JavaScript">JavaScript</option>
              <option value="Python">Python</option>
              <option value="PHP">PHP</option>
              <option value="C#">C#</option>
              <option value="Ruby">Ruby</option>
              <option value="Java">Java</option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <button className="JoinBtn" onClick={joinChatHandler}>
            Join Chat
          </button>
        </form>
      </main>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Join;
```

spec file:

```
import * as React from "react";
import { shallow } from "enzyme";
import Join from "../../../containers/Join/Join";

describe("MyComponent", () => {
  it("should navigate to chat when click on join btn", () => {
    const joinChatHandler = jest.fn();
    const wrapper = shallow(<Join onClick={joinChatHandler} />);
    wrapper.find("button").simulate("click");
    expect(joinChatHandler).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

How can I test this functionality?
I try to simulate a history object and I get the same error.
thanks.

Comment: Don't use the `new` keyword with the `useHistory` hook - it's not a constructor.

Comment: This is not the problem, the functionality work but the test fails @backtick

Comment: I didn't mean it as an answer, but it is still incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

Found solution:

```
const mockHistoryPush = jest.fn();
jest.mock("react-router-dom", () => ({
  ...jest.requireActual("react-router-dom"),
  useHistory: () => ({
    push: mockHistoryPush,
  }),
}));

describe("click handler", () => {
  it("should navigate to chat when click on join btn", () => {
    const joinFormField = {
      username: "",
      room: "JavaScript",
    };
    wrapper.find("button").simulate("click");

    expect(mockHistoryPush).toHaveBeenCalledWith("/chat", {
      user: joinFormField,
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using :

```
this.props.history.push(""/chat")
```

Comment: This is not the problem, the functionality work but the test fails